# PHP site/script map with dependencies

Tags: php

Just inherited a large PHP 5.3 site and wondered if there were some sort of crawler or site map tool that would identify the files and their dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine PHP version and extension dependencies with PEAR's [PHP_CompatInfo](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CompatInfo) package.  As for PEAR packages the app might be using, you can see what's installed using

```
pear list -a
```

I don't know of a tool that will tell you which external script dependencies are in use other than grep.